# XOR properties .

Tags: algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XOR properties in set of numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219001/xor-properties-in-set-of-numbers)

Say I have `n positive numbers` $A_1$,$A_2$...$A_n$ and $A_k$ is minimum among them. And `d` is a number such that ($A_1$-d) $\oplus$ ($A_2$-d) $\oplus$ .......(An-1-d) $\oplus$ ($A_n$-d) = 0 where 0<=d <= $A_k$ .

I want to know how many `d` are there . I know I can iterate all possible value of `d` and take `XOR` of `n` number every time and find out but complexity in this case is O($A_k*n$) which is O($n^2$) in worst case.

Is their any property of `XOR` which can help us to find `number of d` in less complexity than this ?